# SSIS package writing to CRM 2011 Data type error

Tags: ssis, type-conversion, dynamics-crm-2011, scribe-workbench

[image]We are trying to push a single order in to MS CRM (dev instance) via SSIS package. 
Most of the columns coming from source (staging table) are of data type 'DT_STR' and their mapped fields in CRM are of 'DT_WSTR' data type.

I already looked for the solution on this site but in all cases the question is for converting wstr to str. In my case I need to convert str to wstr. when I run the package I get error saying,

> Column xxxx cannot convert between unicode and non unicode string data type

I have already tried two solution:
1. Right click on the OLE source and convert datatype to wstr and
2. Using 'Data Conversion'

In both cases the error remains the same. Has anyone else had similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

In OLE DB Source properties don't change data types. If you want you can change in

1. SELECT statement in OLE DB source.
2. you can change in 'Data Conversion'
3. Derived Column element

In Derived Column element code is:

```
(DT_WSTR, 50)([YourString])
```

Don't replace column, add new column in Derived column element.

You doing something wrong if you can't convert, you don't give real error message (or picture of your design), real error message is in Output window when you execute the package.

Comment: I have added the screen shot of the error msg. Will try updating my query and see if that works.

Comment: @kmria from screenshot I'm guessing there is Source for data from CRM maybe scripttask and you in this element "get CRM Orders" in properties change type of unicode column to non-unicode or from nvaarchar to varchar. You can't do what, you need to set like this was first time. It would be better if you show that element "Get CRM Orders" and properties for one of the error columns